# Call python script and catch binary output

Tags: python, go, pipe, exec

I want to manipulate an image in go and I already have a script in python to do modify the image. I only need to send the image from python script to go. For that I am doing it in the following way:

Python script:

```
image = image_in_bytes

print (image)
```

Go script:

```
cmd := exec.Command("python", "image.py")
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout) //I need the image in []byte
cmd.Wait()
```

But with the above code golang is waiting forever without any output...

Any idea?

Comment: You should os/exec.Cmd.Wait wait for the command to complete.

Comment: Hi, yeah I am using cmd.Wait() I did not include in the code by mistake (didnt copy it). I upadted the question

Comment: Well, you discard all information which might be helpful debugging this problem. You probably should start with CombinedOutput to see whether you conversion script works at all and if not what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works flawless for me as described below:

```py
>>> with open("osx.png","rb") as imageFile:
...     img = repr(imageFile.read())
>>> imageFile.close()
>>> with open("sample.py","w") as pyfile:
...     pyfile.write(img)
>>> pyfile.close()
```

Then, I manually edited pyfile to look like

```py
img = '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n[remainder skipped for brevity]'
print(img)
```

Las but not least, I ran the following code:

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "sample.py")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout) //I need the image in []byte
    cmd.Wait()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error reading bytes: %s", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Read %d bytes", len(body))

    o, err := os.OpenFile("img.png", os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_WRONLY, 0660)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("opening img.png: %s", err)
    }
    defer o.Close()
    n, err := o.Write(body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("writing image to file: %s", err)
    }
    if n < len(body) {
        log.Fatal("short write")
    }
```

Complete code available under https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/eb47495f68bed4e3cb8073447efdb53d

I guess it is safe to assume that there is something strange with the way you store the image data in the Python file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accept your response, you really help me. I forgot one line in my code... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I did several tries and at the end I put the StdoutPipe after the Start command which I didn't notice before....